# How to run a .bat file using JavaScript in classic ASP

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file, asp-classic

This batch (.bat) file is on another network (that's connected with proper permissions).

The code that I'm trying to use (but it's unfortunately not working) if the following:

In the Head tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function runApp(which) {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run(which, 1, true);
    }
    </script>
```

In the Body tag:

`<font onClick="runApp('file:///WinNet03\test.bat');" style="cursor: pointer;"><u>Run Batch File</u>  </font>`

However nothing's happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `...\test` isn't going to work. `\t` is parsed as a tab (ascii 9), so you're doing `...WinNet03[tab]est.bat`. Why use backslashes at all? it's a url, use `/`

Comment: This looks like a horrible idea to me.  `onClick="runApp('shutdown -s -t 0');"` could easily be injected, or other more treacherous commands.  You'll probably need to add `runat="server"` and `language="JScript"`, if this will even work at all.  And if it doesn't, it's a blessing in disguise.